# File pathing different in init and other function

Tags: python

file fetchenv.py:

```
class FetchEnv():
    def __init__():
        MODEL_XML_PATH = os.path.join('fetch', F'robot.xml')
        ...

    def gen_xml():
        MODEL_XML_PATH = os.path.join('fetch', F'robot.xml')
```

Why does the first MODEL_XML_PATH work, the 2nd says file not found?

The directory structure is:

- pkg/

-- test.py

-- envs/

--- robotics/

---- assets/

----- fetch/

------ robot.xml

I am running a test script instantiating the class FetchEnv() in test.py

How do I reliably get robot.xml in gen_xml() if the above doesn't work?

Comment: where does `FetchEnv().get_xml()` gets invoked?

Comment: both are called in test.py

Answer (score 0):

Okay one way, do like so:

```
    MODEL_XML_PATH = os.path.join(F'{dir_path}/../assets/fetch', F'robot.xml')
```

Comment: just save path to fetch in `self` and then use `os.path.join(self.path_to_fetch,'fetch',F'robot.xml')`